Riemannian metric on genus 2 surface
I would like an explicit formula for a Riemannian metric on a surface $B$ of genus 2. (I want to be able to explicitly integrate functions on $B$ using finite element methods.) I have a construction, and would like to know if it works.
I proceed by analogy to the torus $T$. To construct $T$, we can identify opposite sides of a square. If the square originally lives in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then no singularities appear at the corners, and the flat space metric
$$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$$
is also a metric everywhere on $T$ if we interpret $(x,y)$ as living in the square.
To construct $B$, we can identify the opposite sides of a regular octagon. Certainly if the octagon lives in flat space, the curvature will be singular at the corners since the interior angles add up to more than $2\pi$, so the flat space metric cannot be used everywhere on $B$ (as must be the case since $B$ has negative Euler characteristic). But if we consider a regular octagon in the hyperbolic plane, the angles now add up to $2\pi$ and the angle argument doesn't require a singularity.
So, is it true that the Poincare disk metric
$$ds^2 = \frac{4}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}\left(dx^2+dy^2\right)$$
is a globally defined metric on $B$, if we interpret $(x,y)$ as coordinates in the octagon? Or does something go wrong?
If this doesn't work, is there some other explicit, globally defined metric on $B$?

It works. You should dig around. There’s definitely software that works with hyperbolic surfaces and maybe even does integrals.

But if we consider a regular octagon in the hyperbolic plane, the angles now add up to $2 \pi$ --- um, nope, not without being very careful.
